# Store dynamic array in a Neo4J node property

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying store a dynamic json array in a node, using `Neo4J`.

```
MATCH (n:Users) 
WHERE n.email = 'a@a.com' 
SET n.rated = [{email: 'b@b.com', date: '09/11/2015'}, 
               {email: 'c@c.com', date: '09/11/2015'}]  
RETURN n
```

Also, reading the post: [Cypher query JSON formated result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219936/cypher-query-json-formated-result) I'm just trying with:

```
MATCH (n:Users) 
WHERE n.email = 'a@a.com' 
SET n.rated = [['b@b.com','09/11/2015'],
               ['c@c.com','09/11/2015']] 
RETURN n
```

But I'm getting the error: `Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties.`

Is possible set a json result or an array in node property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @david-makogon states, this cannot be done. I won't repeat his answer here.

I have achieved this previously by storing the JSON as a string.

```
MATCH (n:Users) 
WHERE n.email = 'a@a.com' 
SET n.rated = "[{email: 'b@b.com', date: '09/11/2015'}, 
               {email: 'c@c.com', date: '09/11/2015'}]"
RETURN n
```

This will store the result you want but may require some manipulation when you retrieve it. This may or may not match your requirement.

I have used this approach using serialiazation/deserialization as necessary.

Comment: While this might work, it completely bypasses the advantages of Neo4j, as you cannot search for content within that string unless you retrieve it and search through it.

Comment: True depending on your scenario and what you are trying to achieve. Ordinarily I would not recommend it and would attempt to model my graph to represent the required scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have nested complex data within a node. In your case, you're trying to store a nested array of documents, then attempting an array of arrays. You may only have arrays of primitive types (e.g. an array of string, or an array of integer).

**EDIT** Just adding this, as there seems to be some confusion around using a graph database (specifically, Neo4j). To deal with the type of nested data you're trying to store in an array, you can simply store each of those nested objects as its own node, with a relationship back to the original node (e.g.`[:RATED]`). This would allow you to have your entire list of properties (email, date) on each additional node, and you'd then be able to query this data as you would be able to query any data in the root node of your example.

Comment: Based in the answer of @ceej was possible. I tested it and it's working. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33631958/store-dynamic-array-in-a-neo4j-node-property/33632248#33632248][1]

Comment: Of course you can store anything you want as a string. But now it's not queryable.

Comment: And, If I store a simple array like ["a","b","c"] it's that queryable?

Comment: yes it would, arrays of numbers, strings and booleans are supported

Comment: This should be the right answer as it advocates the correct approach to be used with Neo4j.